# My Gears Are not Shifting Well

Tags: maintenance, gears, mechanical

my gears are not shifting well. i can only shift from 1st to 2nd...i don't know what is the problem
i have shimano revoshift gear enter image description here
here are some images

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It'd be better to integrate the images directly to stackexchange. What do you mean by "not shifting well"?

Comment: I've cleaned your question up by adding the images to the post. Now you should do the same to your mech. It badly needs a service and looking like that it is no surprise you're having trouble shifting. Most of us periodically lube the chain (and clean the bike) to keep everything flexible, but each new image here seems to suggest a new part that is beyond lubing and probably needs replacing.

Comment: I also suggest that you post photos that are in focus. It's kinda hard to see any details.

Comment: From your pictures, the drive train is quite dirty and lacks oil.  (You should *never* see rust on a chain.)  Clean and oil it (there's a good thread on how to do this somewhere) and you should be in much better shape.

Comment: Looking at your third largest cog on the cassette it looks badly worn. That won't stop you changing gears, but it could mean trouble when you do.

Comment: Clean, lube, and take some decent pictures.  You are lucky it has 2 gears.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get out of the lowest (easiest) gears then something is stopping the cable from releasing. There could be a number of reasons for this. The shifter on the handlebars might not be working properly, something may be caught on the cable and pulling it, the cable could be frayed and is snagging on something, or the rear dérailleur could be jammed.

So you should do some diagnostic tests: if you try to put it into highest (fastest) gear and the cable goes slack but the rear dérailleur doesn't move then it's not the shifter, so you can rule that out. If you undo the nut that holds on the cable to the dérailleur and the dérailleur moves, then it's the cable, and if it doesn't then it's the probably the dérailleur.

Comment: Cable stretch would be the opposite.  Would need to loosen before putting the bike in the lowest gear.  And that bike needs a lot more than a cable adjustment.

Comment: Of course. Amended my answer.